# Example Encrypted Media Extensions encryption

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, mpeg-dash, eme

I am new to Encrypted Media Extensions. Is any one have the Encrypted Media Extensions Example or any other link for playing the video in the browser?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This tutorial is a good primer.

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eme/basics/

From the tutorial, the major components:

> - Key System: A content protection (DRM) mechanism.
> - Content Decryption Module (CDM): A client-side software or hardware mechanism that enables playback of encrypted media.
> - License (Key) server: Interacts with a CDM to provide keys to decrypt media.
> - Packaging service: Encodes and encrypts media for distribution/consumption.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/eme